# Understanding $PROP$ set in the book Logic and Structure (Van Dalen).

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Working on the book: Dirk van Dalen. "*Logic and Structure (Universitext)*" (p. 18)

> Definition 1.1.2 The set PROP of propositions is the smallest set X with the properties

> $
> \begin{array}{rl}
> \rm(i)&p_i\in X(i\in N),\bot\in X,\\
> \rm(ii)&\varphi,\psi\in X\Rightarrow(\varphi\wedge\psi),(\varphi\vee\psi),(\varphi\to\psi),(\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi)\in X,\\
> \rm(iii)&\varphi\in X\Rightarrow(\neg\varphi)\in X.\\
> \end{array}
> $

I would like to know:

> $p_i\in X(i\in N),\bot\in X$

- How can I instantiate this statement when verifiyng a string of symbols belongs to PROP ?
- Is the comma an **and** connective ?
- What is $N$?
- Why is bottom symbol there ?

> $((p \land q) \to p)$

- How can I show this statement belongs to PROP ?

P.S.: I am already aware of similar questions but they do not address my questions, I think.

Comment: See [this very similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748821/why-%c2%ac%c2%ac-bot-not-in-prop)

Comment: The def is a "recipe" to build complex formulas. Start from basic symbols: $p_i$ and $\bot$ and apply the rules (i)) and (iii) to produce new members of $\text {PROP}$: $(\lnot p_1), ( \lnot \bot), ((\lnot p_1) \land \bot)$ and so on.

Comment: How can check if a string of symbols is in $\text {PROP}$ ? Decompose it, starting from the innermost connective (count parenthesis): $\to$. It is of the form $(\varphi \to \psi)$ ? If yes, repeat the procedure with $\varphi$ and $\psi$ until you arrive to the atoms ($p_i$ and $\bot$) or stop when you find that some rules are not satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Mauro Allegranza. I appreciate it. I see now this is a "recipe". However, I saw the post you linked. I am not clear on how to show a specific string of symbols does not belong to PROP. Suppose I want to show $\lnot \bot \notin PROP$, I am not sure it suffices to show I cannot construct it using rules of formation. There is something regarding a smaller set that I am not sure I grasp. Could you give some insight ?

Comment: $\lnot \bot$ does not belong to $\text {PROP}$ because it does not start with a left parentheses. See van Dalen, page 9-10.

Comment: Thank you, @Mauro Allegranza. Of course, you are right. I just wondered how can I prove it using the construction "recipe".

Comment: It's the same; according to the construction recipe a correct formula must be: either (i) a single symbol, in which case it is one of $p_i$'s or $\bot$, and this is not the case; or (ii) a complex formula, in which case it must be enclosed between a pair of parentheses: the left one "(" and the right one ")", and this is not the case. Thus, it is not an element of $\text {PROP}$.

Comment: - @Mauro Allegranza, very sensible explanation. Thank you. The proof the author gives in the link you provided is really complex. Following a chain of reasonings, he concludes that a specific string cannot belong to PROP since X is not the smallest subset. Your explanation is more comprehensible.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can you tell me why he took the name PROP? I mean what does it stand for and why there is a need to create such a set?

Comment: @DeltaPsi - "**Def.1.1.2** (page 7) The set $\text {PROP}$ of propositions ..." because we are working in *propositional logic* (calculus). More usually called the set $\text {WFF}$ of (well-formed) formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $p_i\in X(i\in N),\bot\in X$

> - How can I instantiate this statement when verifiyng a string of symbols belongs to PROP ?

You can instantiate any propositional symbol or $\bot$: $p_1$ is $\in PROP$ according to this clause, $p_{354}$ is $\in PROP$ according to this clause, $\bot$ is $\in PROP$ according to this clause.

> - Is the comma an **and** connective ?

Yes.

> - What is $N$?

It should be $\mathbb{N}$. The $(i \in N)$ just indicates that the $i$'s are running indices to number the propositional symbols.

> - Why is bottom symbol there ?

Because it is an atomic formula. Unlike the other connectives, it does not take any other formulas to form a new formula, and thus belongs in the base case together with the propositional symbols.

> $((p \land q) \to p)$

> - How can I show this statement belongs to PROP ?

Strictly speaking you can't, because according to the definition introduced up to this point, there exist only indexed propositional symbols starting iwth $p$. But it is customary to use $p, q, r$ in practice; if we incoporate these into clause (i), one can prove by induction on the structure of the formula:

1. $p \in PROP$ (by (i), with $p_i = p$).
2. $q \in PROP$ (by (i), with $p_i = q$).
3. Since $p \in PROP$ and $q$ in $PROP$, $(p \land q) \in PROP$ (by (ii), with $\phi = p$ and $\psi = q$).
4. Since $(p \land q) \in PROP$ and $p \in PROP$, $((p \land q) \to p) \in PROP$ (by (ii), with  $\phi$ = $(p \land q)$ and $\psi = p$).

Comment: I can't thank you enough, @lemontree. I hope you can clarify some points. When you say: "$p \in PROP$ (by (i))", are you instantiating set $X$ to $PROP$ ? Are there implicit Universal Quantifiers in front of those conditions ? Is there some ND rule that allows one to conclude "$p \in PROP$ (by (i))".

Comment: 1) No. I am instantiating the meta-variable $p_i$ with the concrete propositional symbol $p$. The distinction between $X$ and $PROP$ is just that $X$ can be any set in which at least all of these elements are contained, but possibly additional stuff not part of the inductive clauses, whereas $PROP$ is the restriction to only these elements specified by the clauses. Yes, this looks a bit clumsy, and often this restriction is made implicitly. 2) Yes, the $i$, $\phi$'s and $\psi$'s are implicitly universally quantified.

Comment: 3) No. The reasoning about which strings are part of the language takes place not in some formal proof system like ND, but informally in the meta langugae (mathematical English).

Comment: Thank you so much, @lemontree. I see now there is no underlying ND system. However, suppose I want to show $(\lnot(\lnot \bot)) \in PROP$. Would be possible to use common inference rules ? I detail.

Comment: I start with $p_i\in PROP(i\in N) \land \bot\in PROP$. By $\mathbf{\land E}$, I derive $\bot\in PROP$. Using $\mathbf{\forall E}$ and (iii), I get $\bot \in PROP \to (\lnot\bot)\in PROP$. By $\mathbf{\to E}$, I derive $(\lnot\bot)\in PROP$. Using $\mathbf{\forall E}$ and (iii), I get $(\lnot \bot) \in PROP \to (\lnot(\lnot\bot)) \in PROP$. Then, by $\mathbf{\to E}$, I finally get $(\lnot(\lnot\bot)) \in PROP$.

Comment: One detail: in your post, you say: "$q \in PROP$ (by (ii), with $p_i = q$), did you mean by (i)... ?

Comment: No, as said, this reasoning does not proceed by formal inference rules, but informally like shown in the last paragraph. For the new example: 1. $\bot \in PROP$ (by (i)); 2. $(\neg \bot) \in PROP)$ (by (iii), $\phi = \bot$); 3. $\neg \neg \bot \in PROP$ (by (ii), $\phi = \neg \bot$). This is not about semantically valid inferences, which is what ND is for, it's about what is grammatical to even write down.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo; fixed it.

Comment: Very much appreciated, @lemontree.

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo on your last example. On 3, it should be $(\lnot (\lnot \bot)) \in PROP$.

Comment: Yes, that's right.