# Understanding the concept of “truth assignment”.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Working on the book: Derek Goldrei. "*Propositional and Predicate Calculus*" (p. 40)

The author briefly introduces the concept of a function *v*:

> We talked informally about knowing whether, in a particular set of circumstances, each propositional variable is true or false. More formally and elegantly, thsi set of circumstances is a function $v \colon P \to \{T,F\}$, where $P$ is the set of propositional variables in our language.

Before introducing the concept of *truth assignment*, explains:

> Let $Form(P, S)$ be the set of all formulas built up from propositional variables in a set $P$ using connectives in a set $S$ which includes $\land$. We shall say that a function $v \colon Form(P,S) \to \{T,F\}$ respects the truth table $\land$ if
> $$
>   v((\theta \land \psi))=
>     \begin{cases}
>        T,  &\text{if } v(\theta))=v(\psi)=T\\
>        F, &otherwise, \\
>      \end{cases}
> $$
> for all formulas $\theta, \psi \in Form(P,S)$.

I see how function $v$ respects the truth table of $\land$. My question is:

- In which way are the truth value of $v(\theta)$ and $v(\psi)$ determined in that piecewise function ?
- What is the criteria for deciding whether $v(\theta)$ (or any propositional variable) is going to be $T$ or $F$ ?

Comment: See [van Dalen](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA17), page 17 for the definition and the basic result: "If a valuation is only given for atoms then it is, by virtue of the definition by recursion [see your previous post], possible to extend it to all propositions. "

Comment: Thank you so much, @Mauro ALLEGRANZA. That's exactly what I do not understand. Could you explain a little bit ? What does "...possible to extend it to all propositions", mean ? I see how the value of compound formulas is computes; I just do not see it when it comes to atoms. I mean, what determines the assignment of T or F to an atomic formula.

Comment: Thank for the offering. I will appreciate if you could clarify the meaning of "...possible to extend it to all propositions". Also, is perhaps the assignment to atoms random ? I feel this is not really complicated but a detail evades me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure (5th ed., 2013)](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA17), page 17 for the definition and the basic result:

> "If a valuation is only given for atoms then it is, by virtue of the definition by recursion, possible to extend it to all propositions."

What is a *valuation* ? Simply a function: $v : \text {PROP} \to \{ 0,1 \}$,

where [see [page 7](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA7)] $\text {PROP} = \{ p_0, p_1, \ldots \}$ is the collection of *proposition symbols*.

*Side condition*: van Dalen uses $\bot$ and consider it as a $0$-ary connective. Thus, he needs the clause: for every valuation $v$ we must have: $v(\bot)=0$.

Silly examples of valuations:

> $v(p_i)=0$, for every $i$; $v'(p_i)=1$, for every $i$.

Starting with an assignment $v$, we can easily show how the truth tables for the basic connectives [see [page 18](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA18)] give us the recipe for computing the truth value for a formula $\varphi$ whatever.

Consider the formula $((p_0 ∧ p_1) → (\lnot p_0))$ [similar to the example used in your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849411/understanding-prop-set-in-the-book-logic-and-structure-van-dalen)] and build the usual truth table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p_0&p_1&(p_0 \land p_1)&(\lnot p_0)&((p_0\land p_1)\to(\lnot p_0))&\\\hline
1&1&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1&1\\
\end{array}$$

Consider now the following valuation: $v(p_0)=0$ and $v(p_1)=1$. It simply amounts to the third line in the table above.

*Note*: as we can imagine [but we can prove it: see **Lemma 2.2.3**, page 18], what matters are only the value that the valuation assigns to the propositional symbols occurring into the formula.

The "recipe" is:

> *(i)* $v(p_0)=0$; thus $v[(\lnot p_0)]=1$.

> *(ii)* $v(p_0)=0$ and $v(p_1)=1$; thus $v[(p_0 \land p_1)]=0$.

> *(iii)* $v[(p_0 \land p_1)]=0$ and $v[(\lnot p_0)]=1$; thus $v[((p_0 \land p_1)\to (\lnot p_0))]=1$.

*Note*: in computing the truth value of the formula, we have followed the *formation sequence* [see **Definition 2.1.4**, page 9] of the formula:

> $p_0, p_1, (p_0 \land p_1), (\lnot p_0), ((p_0 \land p_1)\to (\lnot p_0))$.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately the truth value $v(\varphi)$ of any formula $\varphi$ is determined by the truth values that $v$ assigns to the propositional variable appearing in $\varphi$. Consider, for instance the following formula $\varphi$:

$$(p\land\neg q)\lor(r\land q)\to p$$

If $v(p)=F$, $v(q)=T$, and $v(r)=F$, then:

- $v(\neg q)$ must be $F$ in order to respect to truth table for $\neg$;
- $v(p\land\neg q)$ must then also be $F$ in order to respect the truth table for $\land$;
- $v(r\land q)$ must be $F$ for the same reason;
- $v\big((p\land\neg q)\lor(r\land q)\big)$ must be $F$ in order to respect the truth table for $\lor$; and finally
- $v(\varphi)$ must be $T$ in order to respect the truth table for $\to$.

If we change the truth value of $r$ by setting $v(r)=T$, we must then have $v(r\land q)=T$, $v\big((p\land\neg q)\lor(r\land q)\big)=T$, and $v(\varphi)=F$.

In practice truth assignments are very often presented in the form of tables showing the truth values assigned to a particular formula under all possible assignments of truth values to its propositional variables. In this case we’d have the following table, and we could read off that $v(\varphi)=T$ for all truth assignments to $p,q$, and $r$ except the one mentioned immediately above, the one in the fifth line of the table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p&q&r&p\land\neg q&r\land q&(p\land\neg q)\lor(r\land q)&\varphi\\\hline
T&T&T&F&T&T&T\\
T&T&F&F&F&F&T\\
T&F&T&T&F&T&T\\
T&F&F&T&F&T&T\\
F&T&T&F&T&T&F\\
F&T&F&F&F&F&T\\
F&F&T&F&F&F&T\\
F&F&F&F&F&F&T
\end{array}$$

Comment: Very clear. Thank you so much, @Brian M. Scott ! I see what you explain about respecting the truth table of logical connectives. But, in which way the value of $v(\theta)$ is determined ($\theta$ being an atomic proposition) ?

Comment: Taking a simple example, I know the value of $\sqrt{4}$ is going to be $2$, but in terms of truth assignments, I cannot see a predictable way of determining if a certain proposition is going to be true or false.

Comment: Perhaps, there is a subtle point about functions that I'm not getting...

Comment: @F.Zer: I’m not quite sure what you’re asking. Are you asking how, if $p$ is a propositional variable, one determines the truth value of $p$? That’s not a question with which propositional logic deals: propositional logic deals with how truth values of propositions are correctly combined.

Comment: Thank you, @Brian M. Scott. Your comment sheds some light. What I would like to know is: in which way function $v$ assigns truth values. I see the type of $v : PROP \to \{0,1\}$ but do not see a formula defining in which way $v$ assigns values.

Comment: @F.Zer: And in general you won’t see such a formula. Giving specific meaning to the individual propositional variables and determining their truth values are tasks for another domain; propositional logic deals with the correct manipulation of those values once they’ve been assigned. It deals with the question of whether an argument is logically valid, independent of whether its premises and conclusions are true or false.

Comment: Oh, thank you @Brian M. Scott ! So, suppose $v$ is defined explicitly as $v(p)=F$, $v(q)=F$ and $v(r)=F$. A function is a special case of relation and, in this case, the subset {(p, F), (q, F), (r, F)} is a subset of the Cartesian product $\{p,q,r,...\} \times \{T,F\}$ and meets the condition of a function (every element of the domain is paired with exactly one element with the codomain), we can say it is a _truth assignment_. Only those conditions need to be met. Is this correct ?

Comment: @F.Zer: Yes, that’s correct. For instance, the truth table in my answer shows every one of the $8$ possible truth assignments to the three variable $p,q$, and $r$, one per line.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are thorough, but they overcomplicate matters by quite a bit
by being too formal. A *truth assignment* `ν` is simply a *row of values of
atomic propositions in a truth table*, nothing more, nothing less.

This row of atomic proposition values can be thought of as a function
`ν(φ) → {T, F}`, which is true or `T`, if the value of the formula `φ` is true
with that combination of values of atomic propositions `ν` and false or F, if
the fomula `φ` is not true with said values. For example, if it is `raining`
and `cloudy` or `raining = T` and `cloudy = T`, then

```
raining ∧ cloudy = T ∧ T = T ,
```

and the sequence `raining cloudy = T T = ν` for which `ν(φ) = ν(raining ∧ cloudy) = T`.

Another way of writing the fact that `ν(φ) = T`, or that `φ` is true with the
observed combination of values of the atomic propositions, is `ν ⊧ φ`, or `ν` is
a *model* of the formula `φ`. If `φ` is *not* true with the given combination
of atomic proposition values `ν`, we say that `ν ̸⊧ φ`, or  that `ν` is a *counter
model* of `φ`.

Anyways, thinking about this in terms of truth tables is in my opinion more
illustrative than most alternative presentations.