# Let the language $\mathcal L_1^{=}$, with the following set of non-logical symbols {a, b, H, K}...

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let the language $\mathcal L_1^{=}$, with the following set of non-logical symbols {a, b, H, K}, where a, b are individual constants and H, K are 1-ary predicates, and a classic semantics, prove the following statements.

a) The (closed) formula((Ha $\to$ Ka) $\land$ Ka) $\to$ Ha) it's invalid.

b) The formula Hb $\to$ ($\lnot$ Hb $\to$ Kb) it's valid.

a) Ha = true and Ka = true so it is true.

Ha = true and Ka = false so it is true.

Ha = false and Ka = true so is false.

Ha = true and Ka = true so it is true.

So, it's invalid.

b)
Hb = true and Kb = true so it is true.

Hb = true and Kb = false so it is true.

Hb = false and Kb = true so it is true.

Hb = true and Kb = true so it is true.

So, it's valid.

I used the truth table to get dos values, sorry I don't know how to build one here, my idea is correct ? The statement a) has an extra parentheses, but I don't know if that is a mistake or on purpose.

Comment: a) Correct. See [Affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent#Formal_description)

Comment: b) Correct. See [Ex falso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion#Symbolic_representation)

Comment: For truth table, you can copy-paste it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856018/understanding-the-concept-of-truth-assignment)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the table link. But if you could take one more question it would be great. I was reading and saw that when it comes to semantic consequences, using the truth table doesn't always work. But in this case it works because we are dealing with a constant and we don't have symbols like $ \ forall $, am I right or did I get it wrong?

Comment: Exactly; you problem is a "propositional problem" in disguise: you have no free variables nor quantifiers, but only atomic sentences. Thus, you can treat them as propositional variables of prop logic.